# Trying to calculate partial sums of e^10 in matlab and failing

Tags: matlab

I've created the function:

```
function [sum] = func(a,b)
sum = 0;
for i = 0:b
    sum = sum + ((a.^i)/(factorial(i)));
end
```

I'm trying to calculate the partial sums of 10,20,...100 elements in the sum, so I defined:

```
>> x

x =

    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100
```

When I enter the command y = f(10,x) into the console I get:

```
>> y = func(10,x)

y =

    1.2842e+04
```

Which is 1) clearly wrong and 2) not a vector.
What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I posted that question as well, I thought I had an answer but in the end it doesn't work, so I'm looking for some more help.

Comment: If the answer doesn't fully answer your question, don't accept it. Let's close this question and continue at the original.